# vbscript connect to sql server run query save results to csv

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I am trying to create a script that connects to sql server, selects some data, and saves the results to a csv. Windows Authentication is enabled in Sql Server.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Dim connect, sql, resultSet, pth, txt

Set connect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=server\instance;Database=pm;Trusted_Connection=True;"
connect.Open

sql="SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1 order by col1, col2"

Set resultSet = connect.Execute(sql)

pth = "d:\test.csv"
Set txt = fs.CreateTextFile(pth, True)

On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not resultSet.eof
  txt.WriteLine(resultSet(0) & "," & resultSet(1))
  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop

resultSet.Close
connect.Close
Set connect = Nothing
```

I get error:

```
d:\vbs_test.vbs(5, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server: Invalid authorization specification
```

Comment: Try using `Trusted_Connection=Yes` insead of `true` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677227(v=vs.85).aspx